# Determinant and inverse of a positive-definite band matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I have the following positive definite matrix given by

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&c&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ b&a&b&c&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ c&b&a&b&c&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&c&b&a&b&c&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&c&b&a&b&c&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&c&b&a&b&c&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&c&b&a&b&c&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&c&b&a&b&c \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&c&b&a&b \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&c&b&a
\end{pmatrix}_{10\times 10}
\end{equation*}
$a>0; \quad b\,\,and \,\, c \in \mathbb{R},$

You can think of the above matrix as a variance-covariance matrix, so the diagonal elements are variances and the off-diagonal elements are covariances

what I am interested in is finding the inverse for such a matrix with dimensions of $n \times n$. I tried to figure out the pattern by computing the inverse of smaller dimensions matrices with the same structure, yet I could not recognize a pattern.

Comment: Check here:  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042712003081

Answer (score 1):

there is a pattern in these, I picked integer values

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 12 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 24 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 12 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 115 }{ 48 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 24 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 24 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 12 }  &  \frac{ 34 }{ 115 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 12 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 115 }{ 48 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 273 }{ 115 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 24 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 12 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 34 }{ 115 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$